# How to get Animation from View

Tags: android, android-animation, android-progressbar

I've set an Animation on `ProgressBar` in click event in Adapter

```
ObjectAnimator animation = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(holder.progressbar, "progress", 0, 100);
animation.setDuration(PROGRESS_TIME);
animation.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
animation.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {

@Override
public void onAnimationStart(Animator animator) {
    Toast.makeText(context,"HELL_Start",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animator) {
    //do something when the countdown is complete
    Toast.makeText(context,"HELL_OFF_END",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animator) {
    Toast.makeText(context,"HELL_OFF_Cancel",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animator) { }
});

animation.start();
```

I'm trying to get Animation (when list item values get changed) from the `ProgressBar` by using

`AlphaAnimation animation =  (AlphaAnimation)mProgressBar.getAnimation();`

but it is returning `null`

Comment: Your object animator works independent of the view, so you're not going to be able to get it from the view. But why don't you just reference the very animation you created?

Comment: @dominicoder how to add it for each list item and then reference to it when clicked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the animator object as the associated view's tag.

```
holder.progressbar.setTag(animation);
```

Than retrieve it later:

```
ObjectAnimator animator = (ObjectAnimator) holder.progressBar.getTag();
// Do something with animator
```

Comment: Thanks,It works, not sure if this approach is good or I should add handler for each list item

Comment: Adding a handler for each item would mean one animation would drive them all, which is probably not what you want.

Comment: Maybe you missed calling getTag() to get the ObjectAnimator.

Comment: Oh, yeah, I did - weird. Fixed. Thanks.